# c++ serialization of class object with another class

Tags: c++, serialization

Tried using boost serialize and so far unsuccessful in writing to a file. Here is my code and how can i serialize & deserialize the object **SRegister** in code, **record** is the another class inherited (no idea about the class record member variables and initialized with text file. its an SDK). Please help me with this. Here is the code both .h and .cpp file

```
/**file: student.h**/ 

class students
{  

public:
 students(const char* path): record(path) {}

 ~students(){}

 int Register(string name, int year)
 {
   return record.Register(name, year);
 }

 int map_studentid_name(int index, std::string name)
 {
   student_map.insert(std::pair<int, string>(index, name));
 }


private:
 StudentRecord record;
 std::map<int, string> student_map;

};


/**File: student.cpp**/

#include "student.h"
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

 const char *path_file = "data.txt";
 if ((path_file != NULL) && (path_file[0] == '\0'))
 {
   return (0);
 }

 students *SRegister = new students("school.txt");

 std::ifstream file(path_file);
 std::string str;
 int count = 1;
 while (std::getline(file, str))
 {
   // get the line from text file - name year
   std::string delimiter = " ";
   string name;
   int year;
   size_t pos = 0;
   std::string token;
   while ((pos = str.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos)
   {
     name = str.substr(0, pos);
     str.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
   }
   year = str;


   // Register student in data base
   findex = SRegister->Register(name, year);

   FRegister->map_studentid_name(findex, name);
   count++;
 }

/* Now i neeed to save/ serialize  the SRegister into a file */


}
```

Comment: This is not a [mcve].  There is no inclusion of `boost` anywhere, we don't know what `StudentRecord` is, but we see a lot of irrelevant code that erases from a string and other such things.

Comment: Studentrecord is in .so file (library). Is it possible to serialize an inherited object which is in the library .so ?